# Heroku ActiveRecord Error: PgSQL put null in id field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, heroku

I just deployed a simple Ruby on Rails (3.0.10) application to Heroku. There is a line of code create a new User object like this.

```
User.create(:name => "[name here]", :email => "[email here]")
```

It can run well in my local machine, which is using MySQL. After I deployed it to Heroku, I got an error.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint : INSERT INTO "users" ("id", "name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (NULL, '[name here]', '[email here]', '2011-09-28 03:59:12.908593', '2011-09-28 03:59:12.908593') RETURNING "id"
```

I have no idea what's wrong with my code. Did i miss anything?

Thanks all.

**UPDATE**

Migration

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

Schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20110922071106) do

  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

Comment: yup. i know, but i afraid there isn't any production configuration. it's so weird.... i am having a deeper check.... will update here asap......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just re-create the whole RoR application, and copy all the controllers, models, and views that I built to the new app. It is now running well.

I tried to compare 2 versions and didn't have any result. Will let you guys know if I find out the cause of this.

Thanks all. :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you do this:
(Taken from http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html)

> Replace SQLite with PostgreSQL If you are developing locally using
>   SQLite, you will need to switch to PostgreSQL for deployment to 
>   Heroku. If you don’t want to develop using PostgreSQL locally, you
>   can set up your Gemfile to use SQLite for development and PostgreSQL
>   for production.
>
> To switch from SQLite to PostgreSQL for deployment to Heroku, edit
>   your Gemfile and change this line:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

> To this:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg' 
end 
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. My Gemfile is same as yours suggestion. The problem is still exists.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else looking, I had this same problem. Worked fine in dev, but failed in production with Postgres. The problem I had I tracked back to the CanCan plugin, specifically code I had that was creating a guest user the ability.rb file, if no user object existed. The guest account was suggested in a Railscast. I removed the User.new guest creation command and the problem resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. if you try to reload the schema (on local, dont do it on production obviously), you should see a difference in what you think you have and what the database actually thinks.

```
rake db:schema:dump
rake db:schema:load
```

THIS WILL ERASE YOUR DATA. But you should see a difference in the schema for 'users'. This was my difference:

The fresh dump showed:

```
create_table "posts", :id => :false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "id", :null  => false, :limit=> 8
    t.integer  "object_id",    :limit => 8
    t.string   "post_type"
    t.string   "from_id"
    t.text     "picture_url"
    t.text     "video_source"
    t.integer  "shares"
    t.integer  "likes"
    t.datetime "created_at",                :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                :null => false
    t.integer  "image_size",   :limit => 8
    t.integer  "vid_size",     :limit => 8
end
```

But i know that id is handled by rails and this should be:

```
create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "object_id",    :limit => 8
    t.string   "post_type"
    t.string   "from_id"
    t.text     "picture_url"
    t.text     "video_source"
    t.integer  "shares"
    t.integer  "likes"
    t.datetime "created_at",                :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                :null => false
    t.integer  "image_size",   :limit => 8
    t.integer  "vid_size",     :limit => 8
end
```

If this is also the case for you, simply add to your user model:

```
set_primary_key :id
```

That reset it and it works now. I still don't know the cause of the problem but this fixed it for me.

Comment: Thanks @amankapur91. Do you mean the line `set_primary_key :id` need to be kept in the Model file forever?

Comment: @victorlamhk yes, i know its not ideal but this a really random bug with heroku postrgress. If you switch to aws, and use MYSQL for instance, it doesn't happen.